# How to open Query View in Microsoft Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to open query view in microsoft access 2007 database.
I don't know how to open it.
Please explain me how to open Query View in Access.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

open the table in design view. there will be a 'sql' in bottom right corner. click on that